# Concatenation consumes a lot of memory, how can I optimize it?

Tags: javascript, concatenation, ram

Concatenation consumes a lot of memory. If we consider that the character takes ~2 bytes, then the resulting line of code should take about ~20 MB, but when the code presented below works, the page consumes about 1GB. Tried to use Join, or perform the operation s + = 'q'; in function, etc., nothing helps. How can I optimize, for example in ".net" there is a StringBuilder?

```
var i = 0
       var s = "q";
   while (i <10000000) {
     s + = 'q';
 
     i ++;
   }
```

P.S.

```
let str = Array (10000000) .fill (`g`) .join``;
```

or

```
'g'.repeat (10000000)
```

not suitable, need concatenation.

Comment: `i <10,000,000)` is not right. numbers do not have commas in JavaScript

Comment: What application requires you to show this number of q's?

Comment: experiment to merge a large amount of text into a string.

Comment: Just something to consider: Javascript strings are immutable.

Answer (score 1):

You could still use `join` - you don't need to create the whole array in one go with `fill`:

```
var i = 0;
var a = [];
while (i <10000000) {
    a[i] = 'q';
    i++;
}
var s = a.join('');
```

That way you can "concatenate" whatever characters (or larger strings) are needed into the elements of the array, then finally join them all in one go in one operation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a Http request to the web server which can do this operation and return only the result. I would also try a web worker (new browsers support it), but i'm not sure about memory consumption. But it won't use the UI thread.

And i would break this operation into a set of smaller ones using a setTimeout, making for example 100  100000 character strings, and then concantenate them instead of concantenating 10000000 one char strings.

Comment: What if this _is_ the webserver?  Consider that JavaScript runs in a lot more places than just browsers these days.

Comment: So we need to know more about the context - where it is done.

Comment: Even if it is client/server, I'd hope that dealing with a 10 million character string would be best left on the client rather than transferring it over the network...

Comment: i expanded the answer - first create 100000 character string inside a setTimeout and then concantinate them. It will allow to release memory.

Comment: What about `async/await` can this be used? :)

Comment: async await - can be used, but technically it is  the same